# How to select specific text from the output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nslookup

I am doing nslookup by reading hostname from one csv file and I want to write the FQDN into the another csv file.

This is my code:

```
import subprocess

with open('csv1.csv', 'r') as i, open('csv2.csv', 'w') as o:
   for line in i:
     if line.strip(): # skips empty lines
        proc = subprocess.Popen(["nslookup", line.strip()],
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        o.write('{}\n'.format(proc.communicate(0)))

print('Done')
```

The problem I am facing that it gives all detailed information similarly when done in cmd->nslookup, like the 'SERVER', 'ADDRESS', 'FQDN' and it's IP ADDRESS
Here is the example of one of the hostname:

```
(b'Server:  anything.na.com\r\nAddress:  10.3.56.7\r\n\r\nName:    ABCD12.na.com\r\nAddress:  10.4.67.8\r\nAliases:  abcd12.na.com\r\n\r\n'
```

I only want to extract FQDN name here into the csv file.

Comment: `nslookup` isn't very good for integrating into other programs.  If you have `dig`, try `dig +short`. The obvious solution is to use a Python DNS resolver and not use an external utility at all, though; I like [`dnspython`](http://www.dnspython.org/) though the reference documentation is somewhat intimidating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just find the data you are looking for, using `re`or `split`:

```
import subprocess

with open('csv1.csv', 'r') as i, open('csv2.csv', 'w') as o:
   for line in i:
     if line.strip(): # skips empty lines
        proc = subprocess.Popen(["nslookup", line.strip()],
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        stdout_data, stderr_data = proc.communicate(0)
        fqdn = stdout_data.split(b'Server:  ')[1].split(b'\r\n')[0]
        o.write('{}\n'.format(fqdn))
```

Comment: I am using Python 3.6 and it seems it doesnt have that attribute.It is giving me an error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: `Popen.communicate()` returns a tuple `(stdout_data, stderr_data)`

Comment: @Gelineau Perfect! can you please explain me 
 stdout_data.split(b'Server:  ')[1].split(b'\r\n')[0] -> Why are we using [1] and [0] here for and in what context? what it is exactly splitting? so that if i need to take some other column out then i only have to change that.

Comment: @AlexP. you can brief about it as well :)

Comment: input_text.split(separator) splits the input_text, using separator. When using [0], we take the text before the first separator. When using [1], we take the text after the first separator (and before the second separator if it exists)

Comment: @Gelineau Okay! I tried understanding this statement by implementing it with variation, but still really couldn't get it. So for example, lets say, I only want to extract Name portion which is 'ABCD12.na.com', how is that done? just use [0] and [1] at the same place and change only the string name?

Comment: Try printing `input_text.split('Name:')` then `input_text.split('Name:')[1]`, you'll understand how it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172542/discussion-between-karan-m-and-gelineau).